# how to get a html form element with name is php variable

Tags: php, html

I want to get html form element by post with the name being a php variable

**example** :

```
<form method="post" action="action.php"><input type="submit" name="'.$name.'"></form>
```

**action.php** code:

```
$var=$_POST['What do i put here?'];
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need it to be a php variable?

Comment: whatever is the value of `$name` variale will come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, 
use $_POST array in foreach:

action.php

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
```

i hope it will be helpful.

Comment: what if i have in my form several input that i wish to get elements form  by post like :   `<form method="post" action="action.php"><input type="submit" name="'.$name.'"> <input type="text" name="'.$course.'"</form>` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply put it like 
 
`$_POST["{$name}"];`

or
 
you can concatenate it like
`$_POST['abc_'.$name];`

To make it more clear
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$name = 'name';
$var  = $_POST[$name];
```

The result will display the value of the **name** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: `print_r($_POST);`

This is print all values with parameter.

Comment: Here is now what i want to do , i want to retrieve the element of the post one by one . i tried all the solution given above but it does not work .Example :`echo $POST[$name];`

Comment: This is just print all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it .
`<form method="post" action="action.php"><input  type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$name.'">`

`action.php:  $var=$_POST['name'];  echo $var;`

it displays the value of the input which is $name.

input can be whatever you want !!